# Why is {"1":1} illegal javascript in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, syntax-error

Why is

```js
{"1":1}
```

illegal JavaScript in Firefox?  Chrome and Edge accept it, and does exactly what you'd expect, but in Firefox it generates

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

Why? Fwiw Firefox's `JSON.parse('{"1":1}');` accepts it, and does as expected (using Firefox 115.6.0esr if that's relevant)

Comment: do you use it as it stand? like a block statement?

Comment: @NinaScholz yup screenshot https://i.imgur.com/HkuvFRV.png

Comment: it is a block syntax with a label without following block.

Comment: @NinaScholz huh.. in that case, i guess the question should be "why does chrome/edge accept it" ?

Comment: What are you talking about ? I have no problem with `let bob = {"1":1 };` on Firefox.

Comment: @MisterJojo try just ```{"1":1};``` without assigning/passing it to anything

Comment: I have the same error on Chrome, no script can accept this line of code

Comment: @MisterJojo works fine in chrome

Comment: how can you do that ?

Comment: @MisterJojo i'm failed, worked in console

Comment: Oh!, I hadn't thought of this kind of test. This whole story clearly shows that on this kind of test, the Firefox JS interpreter does the job correctly. which is not the case on Chrome.